# PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA bsod while installing Kali Linux on virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, bsod, kali-linux

I have a problem with setting virtual machine.  I tried installing Kali Linux with these parameters:

- Memory - 256 MB
- Processor - 2 cores
- SCSI - 16 GB

If i try to install it, I get either console error, or just pitch black screen. Restart it? Well, [here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBAix.jpg)!

How do I install it successfully? Maybe I need more memory space or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SCSI - 16 GB   --   This space is too small for Kali.  My Kali machine is 26 GB.

Memory - 256 MB --- Memory is too small. Default Kali is 64-bit and needs 2 GB minimum.

Make a new VM:  Assign 3 GB memory; 50 GB disk space; and 1 CPU 2 cores  and that should work.  That is roughly what I am running here.

Overall, if you have small machine, only apply half the overall memory and CPU of the total host resources for the VM.

Use the Kali bare metal ISO (Kali download site) and make a new Virtual Machine from the ISO.

Posted from my Kali 2023.3 64-bit Virtual Machine.